# Creating registers from excel members database, if member is classed as 'current'

Tags: database, excel, vba

I'm new here so I apologise if this question has been answered before, but I did have a good search before I posted. This is half a database design question, and half an excel function / macro question.

In a nutshell, I am creating a members database in excel, so each row will be a complete set of data about a person, will all personal details and emergency contact details etc. Right at the end of each row, I want a column that says whether they are 'current' or 'past' members.

Now, I want to be able to generate registers from this database, so the macro (I think it would have to be a macro) would need to look down the whole 'current / past' column, and for any row which had 'current' then copy firstname and surname to a new table.

It's also worth mentioning that the members actually attend different clubs, but is it easier to just have different databases for each club, rather than a central database?

I'm not hugely experienced in advanced excel stuff, I'm ok with simple macro stuff, but this conditional data stuff has me slightly flummoxed. Any help that you guys could offer would be appreciated!

Many thanks.

Comment: simple `filter` excel feature is not advanced excel stuff which could be quite useful in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you want to do this with excel? Maybe a simple Acess database would be suited to your project?
If you want to use excel  take a look on the "Table" / "Pivot Table" features of excel - of you use their filter functions well, there is no need for a Macro solution.

To your last question: Using a table you could simply add a "Club" column and filter by it. But this does not work when a person attends multiple clubs. Then you would have different tables for each club or multiple club columns - all that does not work well, a real database would work better unt these circumstances.

Comment: Thanks Christian, as I'm still in the planning stages I am not tied to using excel. I will have a look at access to see if this suits my needs more. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Please not that I do not advocate Acess - it can be a pain, but if your project is small, it should be ok. A full blown database would be a lot of hassle.